# Android: OkHttpClient response message for error code 404

Tags: android, error-handling, okhttp

When working with HttpURLConnection and I get an http error code 404, HttpURLConnection::getResponseMessage returns me a useful message ("Not Found").

Using the okhttp3.OkHttpClient (same URL), I do not get such a useful message.
I tried response.message(), response.body().string(),... but no luck.

I would expect a similar message as HttpURLConnection provides.
Any ideas how to get such a message I can show to the user? Not everybody knows the meaning of error codes.

Comment: "HttpURLConnection::getResponseMessage returns me a useful message ("Not Found")"-- it returns a useful message in English. Overall, few people can read English. If there are specific HTTP responses for which you want to display, you may be better served mapping them to your own string resources, so you can have translations. Regardless, by my read of the docs, it should be [`message` on `Response`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/message/) -- what are you getting for that, since you imply it is not working?

Comment: response.message(), response.body().string() and whatever I tried, returns me an empty string.